# InvalidOperationException: The view was not found

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, class-library

I have an ASP.Net project and I want to use a class library project for creating reusable Razor view components. I added `AspNetCore.Mvc` and `AspNetCore.Razor.Tools` references to my class library project.

I create the `ViewComponent` class inside `Components/DataTableComponent.cs` file:

```
namespace Rasha.Utility.Components
{
    public class DataTableComponent:ViewComponent
    {
        public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync()
        {
            var model = new DataTableModel()
            {
                Name = "Alliiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii"
            };
            return View("Default.cshtml", model);
        }
    }
}
```

And view inside `Views/Shared/Components/DataTableComponent/Default.cshtml` file.

This is my class library .csproj file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp1.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools" Version="1.1.0-preview4-final" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <EmbeddedResource Include="Views\Shared\Components\**\*.cshtml" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Why I getting this error:

> InvalidOperationException: The view 'Components/DataTableComponent/Default.cshtml' was not found. The following locations were searched:
>   /Areas/Administration/Views/Customer/Default.cshtml

It seems the compiler looking for view in my MVC project instead of the class library project.

Thanks.

Comment: try View("~/Views/Shared/Components/DataTableComponent/Default", model) instead of View("Default.cshtml", model);

Comment: @Steve new error: InvalidOperationException: The view 'Components/DataTableComponent/~/Views/Shared/Components/DataTableComponent/Default' was not found.

Comment: how did you structure your folders??

Comment: @Steve which folders? I said I have two files:
1. in ProjectRoot/Components/DataTableComponent.cs
2.in ProjectRoot/Views/Shared/Components/DataTableComponent/Default.cshtml

Comment: mvc project should create a Views folder under the root for you. Did you remove that?

Comment: @Steve No in MVC project I have my action and views.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My dream came true:

[Creating a Razor Class Library project in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/ui-class?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=visual-studio)  is available now.